# jQuery добавить класс только видимым блокам по их индексу в выборке

Tags: html, jquery, css

Проблема заключается в следующем, есть HTML, к примеру:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно добавить класс "large" всем элементам, соответствующим селектору `:nth(2n+3)`:

```
$('.wrap .item:nth-child(2n+3)').addClass('large');
```

При загрузке страницы все работает отлично, но есть функционал, который скрывает некоторые элементы в различном порядке и класс "large" нужно добавлять только видимым элементам и в таком случае `:nth-child()` уже не работает, так как нумерация идет по всем дочерним элементам, независимо от того, видим он или скрыт.

Нужно добавить класс "large" всем элементам, которые можно выбрать с помощью псевдокласса `:nth-child(8n+3)`, `:nth-child(8n+6)`, `:nth-child(6n+3)`, `:nth-child(6n+4)`, `:nth-child(4n+2)`, `:nth-child(4n+3)`, выше был просто как пример.

Comment: Вместо псевдокласса просто перебрать элементы циклом и на нужные повесить класс

Comment: Думаю, что вам надо как-то переработать логику навешивания этого класса. Навешивать класс одновременно на такое количество с виду рандомных селекторов кажется чем-то неуловимо неправильным.

Comment: Попробуйте применить конструкцию $.is() Например: $('.item').is(':visible')

Answer (score 0):

С самого начала запустим функцию `addClassLarge()`, которая убирает везде добавленный класс `large`, а затем проходит по видимым элементам при помощи селектора `:visible` и по условию `(index + 1) % 3 == 0` (что равняется селектору `:nth-child(3n + 3)`) добавляет класс large.

Затем просто достаточно при скрытии элементов перезапускать эту функцию.

```js
$(function() {
  addClassLarge();
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.item:visible').each(function(index) {
      if((index + 1) % 2 == 0) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
    
    addClassLarge();
  });
  
  function addClassLarge() {
    $('.item').removeClass('large');
    
    $('.item:visible').each(function(index) {
      if((index + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('large');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.item.large {
  border-color: red;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
  <div class="item">19</div>
</div>

<button>Hide some elements</button>
```

Comment: Sasha Omelchenko, пробовал этот вариант, но столкнулся с проблемой написания этих самых условий, собственно, как и сейчас...не могли бы вы написать условие, которое ровно, к примеру селектору :nth-child(8n+3), чтобы уловить смысл, а остальные я уже думаю сам напишу.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bwwrsqbk/ вот вам пример с несколькими формулами.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: @AndriiTiuliupa если ответ вам помог, то ответьте его принятым.